# Which should I use and when: node_load() or entity_load()?

Tags: entities

Title says it all.

I understand that entity_load provides a performant and efficient means to load multiple nodes whilst reducing database queries, so I presume in that instance I should be using entity_load(). But when I just want one node, which should I use? And will node_load() be deprecated in d8 in favour of the more generic entity_load() api?

I guess the same question goes for the familiar user_load() too.

Comment: Ugh... should have read the code a little first.

Node_load is just a wrapper with a few argument checks for node_load_multiple, which is itself a wrapper for entity_load. So performance won't be different for either, except by calling entity_load() directly you perhaps save yourself a few additional function calls.

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/7 and http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`node_load` is just a fancy wrapper for `entity_load`.

That is `node_load` calls `node_load_multiple` which is a wrapper for `entity_load`. This means that performance wise there isn't really much of a difference, which function you use, unless you have to load a lot of nodes.

`node_load` has many advantages over `entity_load`

- It's simpler
- It increases code readability
- it returns the node object instead of an array with the node object(s)

So in all, `node_load` is a convenience that you always should use whenever possible, then resort to `node_load_multiple` for cases where you need to load many more nodes.

`entity_load` should be used for loading entities when you don't know the type, or have it stored in a variable, in which case you can do

```
entity_load($type, ...);
```

Comment: after all `node_load()` is what we are used to.

Answer (score 9):

Use node_load() when you have a single node to load and node_load_multiple() when you have more of them. Use entity_load() directly when you don't know the entity type in advance, for example `entity_load($type, array($id))`.

Note that entity_load() is inconsistently named, it should actually be entity_load_multiple(), as it allows to load multiple results and returns an array of results.

Answer (score 5):

[`node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/7) is the function that existed before the entity API was introduced in Drupal 7. The difference with [`entity_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/entity_load/7) is that it accepts parameters that are specific for the loading a node object, such as `$vid`.
The function calls [`node_load_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7); it is helpful for compatibility reason, and because it requires less parameters.

```
$node = node_load($nid);
```

```
$nodes = entity_load('node', array($nid));
```

In Drupal 8, `node_load()`, `node_load_multiple()` and `entity_load()` are deprecated. This they are removed when Drupal 9 will have its stable release).
Furthermore, in Drupal 8 calls to those functions need to be changed, since in Drupal 8:

- [`node_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/8.8.x) doesn't use `$vid` as second parameter
- [`entity_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21entity.inc/function/entity_load/8.8.x) and [`node_load_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/8.8.x) don't use `$condition` as second parameter (and it was marked as deprecated already in Drupal 7)